# What is the binomial expansion for $(a+b)^{-1}$?

Tags: binomial-theorem

What is the binomial expansion for $(1+x)^{-1}$?

I really don't know how to solve it using negative powers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

There is not an expansion for this by the usual binomial expansion. However, there is one by the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem), which gives, for $n \in \Bbb Z^+$,

$$(1-x)^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{n-1} x^k$$

Factor out $a$ from your expression and replace adding $b$ with subtracting $(-b)$:

$$(a+b)^{-1} = a^{-1} \left(1- \left(-\frac b a \right) \right)^{-1}$$

Now apply the theorem for $x=-b/a$ and $n=1$.

---

**Footnote:**

You could approach this by the geometric series instead, but this generalizes it somewhat. I used the above solution because "binomial" was specified, but geometric is easier. In the geometric series, we have

$$(1-x)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$

Do the factoring as before and take $x=-b/a$ for the same result.

Answer (score 3):

If $|x| <1$,

$\frac{1}{1+x} = (1+x)^{-1} = 1 -x + x^2 - x^3 \cdots$

Answer (score 2):

Geometric series ($q=-x$):

$\frac{1}{1-q} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n.$

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial expansion:
$$ (x + a)^n = C_0^n x^n + C_1^n x^{n-1} a + C_2^n x^{n-2} a^2 . . . . . C_n^n a^n $$
For $|x|<1$, so the series converges. Therefore we can take $n =-n$

You can form these expansion for $ (x+ a) $ as well, now substituting $1$ in place of $a$ and $ -1 $ in place of $n$
The equation is formed as :
$$ (1+x)^{-1} = 1 - x + \frac { 2 x^2} {2!} 
- \frac { 3*2 x^3 } {3!} +. . .  . (-1)^nx^n $$

Comment: For $|x| < 1$  we can take $n = -n$, the expansion converges

Comment: I edited the answer. Now the last line is correct. The problem is that you have to define clearly what is $(-1)$ choose $k$, because basically the binomial coefficients are only defined for positive $n$ and $k$, and an extension to negative numbers requires care.

Comment: Its a series, not a polynomial. I added three dots.

Comment: Oh like that, then ok. I've further edited the answer for the condition of $n =-n$

Comment: The problem is, for each term in the binomial expansion you increase the $k$ in $C^n_k$ from $k=0$ but you cannot reach $k= n =-1$ by increasing. Unless you increase past infinity, whatever that means.

Comment: The series converges for $|x|<1$

Comment: The series converging doesn't mean it terminates...

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I previously thought that their is some conceptual mistake, but its not. Thankyou for explanation.

Comment: I have added a new answer that supplements yours.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $(1+x) ^n = C^n_0 + C^n_1 x + \cdots + C^n_n x^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$, and that
$$C^n_k = \dfrac {n!} {k! (n-k)!} = \dfrac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)} {k!} $$

Observe that under this definition $C^n_k =0$ for $k>n$ where $n, k\in\mathbb N$ since the numerator contains a zero in the product, so let this binomial sum run for $k\in \mathbb N$, i.e. let the upper limit of $k$ goes to infinity.

We now generalize this to negative $n$, and thus we have:
$$(1+x) ^{-1} = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty C^{-1} _k x^k$$
But $ C^{-1} _k= \dfrac {(-1) (-2) \cdots (-k)} {k!}  = (-1) ^k$

So we have
$$(1+x) ^{-1} = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty (-1) ^k x^k$$